# How to define the type for a nullish value with schema from Zod

Tags: javascript, typescript, zod

I have a type defined with [zod](https://zod.dev/?id=nullish).

Am inexperienced with TypeScript.

The zod object looks like this:

```
import z from 'zod';
const clientSchema = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  details: z.object({
    detail1: z.string().optional()
    }
  }
);
export type ClientSchema = z.infer<typeof clientSchema>;
```

Assigning the `details` of a `client` of type `ClientSchema`, I was hoping
to be able to annotate it's type like this:

```
const details = {
  detail1: <string|null|undefined> ''
}
```

But TypeScript complains:

> Types of property 'detail1' are incompatible.
> Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'."

So now I have created a separate Schema for details:

```
export const detailSchema = z.object({
    detail1: z.string().optional() ,
});
export type DetailSchema = z.infer<typeof detailSchema>;
```

And then declare the object:

```
const details: DetailSchema = {
  detail1: 'a string'
}
```

Is that the expected/recommended approach for sub-objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have `nullable` objects as well, in the case you want a property to be `null` or `undefined` you can do

`property: z.string().nullable().optional()`, in your case this would be:

```
const clientSchema = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  details: z.object({
    detail1: z.string().nullable().optional()
  })
});
```

Which should give you

```
type ClientSchema = {
    name: string;
    details: {
        detail1?: string | null | undefined;
    };
}
```

From this you can extrapolate the `details` schema as

`type DetailSchema = ClientSchema["details"];`

which will give you

```
type DetailSchema = {
    detail1?: string | null | undefined;
}
```

Which you can use as follows:

```
const details: DetailsSchema = {
  details1: ""  // string | null | undefined
}
```